# Why on a $g^{(2)}$ measurement plot, we have multiple peaks for different values of $\tau$ (delay)?

Tags: photons, experimental-physics, quantum-optics, correlation-functions, photon-emission

Why on a $g^{(2)}$ measurement plot, we have multiple peaks for different values of $\tau$ ?

I understand from "Hanbury Brown-Twiss intensity correlation experiment" that the value at $\tau = 0$ tells us if we have bunching or anti-bunching. But why for $\tau$ different from zero we have multiples peaks?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the experiment was done using pulsed excitation. If a photon is detected at $t = t_0$ there is a certain chance that another one is detected shortly afterwards. This is what the measurement is supposed to figure out.

But one pulse period $T$ later ($T\approx 12 \, \text{ns}$ later in the graph) at $t = t_0 + T$ there might be another photon detected, caused by the next pulse. This is the reason for the peak at $\tau \approx 12 \, \text{ns}$. The peaks at other multiples of the period arise analogously. In between the pulses there is only very little chance to detect a photon, because there is no excitation.

To make the measurement meaningful, i.e. to normalize the number of coincidences in order to get $g^{(2)}(\tau)$ the average peak height for large $\tau$ was used. This relies on the assumption that the photodetection events aren't correlated over such long time spans.